# When does WPF subscribe to the PropertyChanged event?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I have a `ClassA` with an `ObservableCollection` property, that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

on my window codebehind I have declared a `ClassA variable`, and initialize it in the Main() method.

i'd expect that `variable.PropertyChanged` would have a WPF event wired to it, but apparently the `PropertyChanged` event remains null

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WPF will subscribe to the PropertyChanged event when you bind to your object.  This is the core way that databinding works.

It actually does this via the [PropertyChangedEventManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventmanager.aspx) using the [WeakEvent pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventmanager.aspx) in WPF.

Comment: So... WPF will also unsubscribe when the binding is discarded (therefore avoiding memory leaks)?

Comment: @NéstorSánchezA. It uses the weak event pattern to avoid the memory leak.  In general, you shouldn't have a leak problem due to WPF binding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this exactly answers your question, but I had similar experiences, and blogged about it [here](http://ianrandallonwpf.blogspot.com/2009/08/binding-to-observablecollection-in-wpf.html).

Essentially, make sure the DataContext is not null when the binding occurs, such that PropertyChanged events can get back to the UI...